# My Windows 7 has suddenly stopped displaying Unicode symbols

Tags: windows-7, gui, unicode

For some strange reason, my computer suddenly doesn't show certain unicode characters anymore! I have no idea what happened.

Affected applications include Windows Explorer (should be Japanese characters), Google Chrome (should be a heart), and Winamp (should be stars):

[image: unicode] [image: unicode] [image]

Russian, German etc. characters are displayed normally. Chrome also displays Japanese script on websites, but not in the GUI. How can I fix it?

> **TL;DR:** A workaround is to put a shortcut with a Unicode name on the desktop so that explorer.exe is the first process to display a Unicode string after booting.

---

**Update:** I have tried to use System Restore to fix it. I needed to go back in time quite a while because the most recent restore points didn't solve it so I used one from the middle of November. After that restore, Unicode symbols were displayed again. Then I updated my system with Windows Update again because those were removed during the restore. After that, the error occurred again! I then did a restore to a point before my new updates, but the error persists, *and* the old restore point (which I used before) is *gone* and there are currently no other snapshots of the system. *Any suggestions on what to do now?*

**Update 2:** I could find a workaround:

> *Control Panel* → *Region and Language* → *Administration* → Change *Language for Unicode-incompatible programs* to *Japanese (Japan)*.

All mentioned programs display their symbols correctly again. However, I don't consider this a fix because these programs are not usually Unicode-incompatible, and it also leads to some (non-serious) artifacts in some programs. I still welcome an answer that tells me what went wrong here and how to fix the issue.

**Update 3:** I think I have isolated the particular Windows Update which causes the error. It is [Slow performance in applications that use the DirectWrite API on a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2505438). I have installed all other updates except this one, and the error did not occur again.

**Update 4:** The true origin of this problem was Chrome, see accepted answer. Workaround: put shortcut with Unicode name on desktop so that explorer.exe is the first process to display a Unicode string after booting.

Comment: Have you attempted a [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/system-restore) to a point when it was working?

Comment: I did, see my update.

Comment: Try reinstalling font. Also what is your default unicode language?

Comment: How do I find that out? However, as you can see in the screenshots, the error occurs with different fonts so I believe it's not a problem with the font.

Comment: This worked for me, and, in fact, I could then change the "Language for Unicode-incompatible programs" back to "English (United States)" which is what is was before, and the fix continued to work.

Comment: What’s really interesting about this is that it does not happen with XP. Obviously Microsoft did something with Unicode handling in Windwos 7 (and probably Vista as well) that has a serious vulnerability which Chrome (hopefully by accident) exploits and breaks Windows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found this interesting tidbit.  It seems that this may have something to do with which application first tries to display a unicode character.

Long story short, I found [this bug for Chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42984) and [a comment in the discussion suggests that this is the case and provides a workaround](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42984#c20) of putting a unicode-named file on the Windows desktop to force Windows to be the first application to render a unicode character:

> "Therefore, as a workaround for this issue, put a file named 火.txt or similar on your Windows Desktop. I suppose this causes Windows Explorer to be the first program to render a [unicode] character."

I tried this approach and sure enough, it worked for me -- without having to change the Language for Unicode incompatible programs."

Comment: After reading through it all again, this might very well be the correct cause for my issue. Thanks for posting it here. +1.

Comment: Seems as if it really was this. Accepted.

Comment: This a) is additionally necessary / useful on Windows 8.  b) Isn't 100% effective.  Maybe another application that starts with Windows sometimes beats Explorer to the desktop?  Can't think of any likely candidates, especially not with the shell:startup lag in Win8.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked a treat. Chrome is seriously broken if it prevents the entirety of Windows and all applications to fail to show Unicode correctly. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Synetech I think this is a bug in Windows. The API should be protected against accidental misuse.

Comment: @FelixDombek, that makes sense and is what I assumed, but even if that’s the case, it is still Chrome that is misusing/exploiting/exposing/triggering a bug in Windows since other browsers don’t cause it to happen. I suppose that can be either a good or bad thing depending on your viewpoint.

Answer (score 3):

1. Change your "Language for Unicode incompatible programs" to Japanese (any other language will do)
2. Change this back to the original value.

It fixed the issue I had with the display of Chinese characters after a Windows update.

[Brian Rothstein left a comment with such an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/371282/my-windows-7-has-suddenly-stopped-displaying-unicode-symbols/411689#comment452511_371282).

Comment: Didn't work for me when switching back. However, I think I know now which Windows Update is responsible. I'll post more info when I'm sure.

Comment: Any update Felix?  I recently ran Windows update and am now having the same problem.  And like you, changing the "Language for Unicode incompatible programs" doesn't stick when changing it back.

Comment: @kiddailey: The fault lies with either http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545698 or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2505438, I'm quite sure. Not installing those two updates has stopped the issue from recurring so far.