# Some Unicode Symbols cannot be shown in IE, Firefox or Chrome with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, unicode, internet-explorer-11

My 64-bit PC running Windows 7 Home Premium version has installed 3 major browsers, IE 11.0.9600.17914 (64-bit), Firefox (just updated to 43.0.3) and Chrome 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit). But all of them are incapable of showing some Unicode symbols, like this one . In Firefox, a rectangle containing the characters "01F" and "917" is shown instead, but in the other two browsers, only a rectangle will be displayed.

Even I go to this page http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%A4%97, the same result occurs.

I have read the other post [My Windows 7 has suddenly stopped displaying Unicode symbols](https://superuser.com/questions/371282/my-windows-7-has-suddenly-stopped-displaying-unicode-symbols), but I think my situation is a bit different. Those characters have never been able to show up. And for more information, there are some observations:

(1) Some symbols for Facebook emoticons can be shown correctly, such as these heart symbols.

(2) I tried the solution suggested in https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10202733484446539 (disabling hardware acceleration for Firefox), but it did not help.

(3) I tried the solution suggested in the accepted answer of [My Windows 7 has suddenly stopped displaying Unicode symbols](https://superuser.com/questions/371282/my-windows-7-has-suddenly-stopped-displaying-unicode-symbols), but it did not work either.

(4) My Windows 7 is in Traditional Chinese, so perhaps the solutions in the US English version may or may not apply. But I'd still welcome and hope for suggestions in English Windows to see if they also apply to the Traditional Chinese version (and due to such hope, I did not specify the language in the question title).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't have a font on your PC that contains . The web page you link to doesn't specify a web font containing that character. Put those two things together and your PC will display .‎

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for your answer, but do you have an idea on what fonts contain these unicode symbols? I tried Arial MS Unicode (using MS Word and paste the symbol there using "Unformatted Unicode Text" option) but it's not working.

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Comment: This comment [Why only some unicode characters are visible on Firefox?](http://superuser.com/posts/comments/635375) might help you ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you very much for your effort! The website www.fileformat.info does help a lot, as the page http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f917/index.htm shows the symbol is very new (included in June 2015). The page http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f917/fontsupport.htm also shows my PC does not have any font to support the above Unicode symbol. Unfortunately their server fonts do not either (the only font that supports is called "Last Resort" but a generic symbol is shown instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite having "Unicode" in the name, Arial Unicode MS does not cover all of Unicode. (I gather from the linked comments that no font can have a glyph for every Unicode character.)

It appears that Firefox, upon discovering a lack of glyph for a character, displays in its place the Unicode character number in hexadecimal. Other browsers just display a box. (U+1F917, as you showed, is called "hugging face.")

I've found that the [Symbola](https://archive.org/download/Symbola/Symbola613.ttf) font covers the majority of the "unusual" Unicode that I've seen. (The link is to a direct download from the Internet Archive.) There used to be a Chrome extension called Chromoji that had SVG versions of essentially every emoji, but it's been taken down from the Chrome store; hopefully it will come back eventually.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried the Symbola font (best of all, it's free for personal use), it worked when I chose it in MS Word and then pasted the unicode symbol. However, the symbol still did not show up in Chrome and IE (didn't check for Firefox yet since the PC I am currently using does not have it). I changed the default font of Chrome to Symbola, restarted Chrome, but still no luck. So I wonder if there are further settings needed. On the other hand, I tried a Chrome Extension called Emojify (available in Chrome Store), it can show some Emojis, but not the U+1F917 used in the question.

Comment: Some further information: I tried Firefox, and when I changed the default font to Symbola, the Unicode symbols like U+1F917 can be shown on webpages such as Facebook. However, for webpages that specify a font which is available in the user's computer, it will be used, meaning that whether the Unicode symbols can be shown depends on the availability of the Unicode symbols in that font.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be talking about [Unicode emoji characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) specifically. You can get the [Emoji One](http://emojione.com) character set in your browser using:

- The [Emoji One Chrome Extension](http://emojione.com/chrome/) (includes extra functionality for writing emoji too)
- The [Emoji One Color SVGinOT Font](https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font), which is a cross-platform, cross-browser font

  - For Windows, download [the latest release](https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font/releases) and install the TTF file (inside the zip file) as you would for any other font.

Emoji One and the font are updated frequently. (Note that the font is created by an independent developer.)